# Magento Admin Grid is Empty

Tags: magento

I am trying to create a custom module.When i click a module menu,empty grid is [displaying](http://postimage.org/image/6s48w45wr/).Log is not showing any errors

Grid.php

```
class Training_Banners_Block_Adminhtml_Banners_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('bannersGrid');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setDefaultSort('banner_id');
        $this->setSaveParamatersInSession(true);


    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection=Mage::getModel('banners/manage')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        Mage::log(var_dump($collection));
        return $collection;
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumn('banner_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('banners')->__('ID'),
            'align'     =>'right',
            'width'     => '50px',
            'index'     => 'banner_id'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('banners')->__('Name'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'name'
        ));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

banners.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_banners_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="banners/adminhtml_banners" name="training.banners" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_banners_index>
</layout>
```

Controller

```
<?php

class Training_Banners_Adminhtml_BanneradminController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function _initAction()
    {
         $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('banners/banners')
         ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Banners Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Banners Manager'));
        return $this;
    }

     public function indexAction() 
     {
        $this->_initAction();
        $this->loadLayout();      
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('banners/adminhtml_banners'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108697/magento-custom-module-grid-not-displaying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Please clear your cache and then logout and login.

Also please check the config.xml file ,whether the block and other declarations are same..