# Magento custom module grid not displaying

Tags: magento

So I'm trying to get a grid to display in my custom module (displaying anything for the time being, I'll worry about the collection once it's working!).

The problem is that the _prepareCollection() and/or _prepareColumns() methods of my grid widget class never seem to get called and the grid never shows (nor do the buttons and header text). (The Magento admin header and footer and navigation display correctly. It's just blank in the middle!)

This is what I have so far:

app/code/local/MyNamespace/Mymodule/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyNamespace_Mymodule>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MyNamespace_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <!-- Define frontend and backend routers -->
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyNamespace_Mymodule</module>
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <!-- /Define frontend and backend routers -->
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <mymodule>
                <class>MyNamespace_Mymodule_Helper</class>
            </mymodule>
        </helpers>  
        <blocks>
            <mymodule>
                <class>MyNamespace_Mymodule_Block</class>
            </mymodule>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <mymodule module="mymodule">
                <title>My Module</title>
                <sort_order>80</sort_order>              
                <children>
                    <items module="mymodule">
                        <title>Manage My Module</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </mymodule>
        </menu>
       <!-- define layout updates -->
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file>
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <!-- /define layout updates -->
    </adminhtml> 
</config>
```

Then my controller:

app/code/local/MyNamespace/Mymodule/controllers/Adminhtml/MymoduleController.php

```
<?php
class MyNamespace_Mymodule_Adminhtml_MymoduleController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
{
    public function indexAction() {
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule');
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Then in my grid container:

app/code/local/MyNamespace/Mymodule/Block/Adminhtml/Mymodule.php

```
<?php
class MyNamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Mymodule extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo  __METHOD__ . " (Line #" . __LINE__ . ")<br/>";
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_mymodule';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'mymodule';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('my header text'); // this is not rendered
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('my button text'); // this is not rendered

    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->setChild( 'grid',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid',
            $this->_controller . '.grid')->setSaveParametersInSession(true) );
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

Then in my grid widget:

app/code/local/MyNamespace/Mymodule/Block/Adminhtml/Mymodule/Grid.php

```
<?php
class MyNamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Mymodule_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('mymoduleGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        echo  __METHOD__ . " (Line #" . __LINE__ . ")<br/>"; // This is never called
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection(); // just a temp collection for the time being

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        echo  __METHOD__ . " (Line #" . __LINE__ . ")<br/>"; // This is never called
        $this->addColumn('id', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('ID'),
          'align'     =>'right',
          'width'     => '10px',
          'index'     => 'id',
        ));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

And finally my layout xml:

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/mymodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_mymodule_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule" name="mymodule" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_mymodule_index>
</layout>
```

There are no errors being shown in the logs and I'm now a bit stumpped and other SO answers don't seem to fit.

Anyone shed any light on why my grid (even an empty one) isn't showing?

Thank you.

**EDIT** Noticed that some classes had the wrong case (Mynamespace should be MyNamespace). Changed them but no difference

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the problem of your layout's handle tag.

It should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <mymodule_adminhtml_mymodule_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule" name="mymodule" />
        </reference>
    </mymodule_adminhtml_mymodule_index>
</layout>
```

For the explanation and few tips, you can read this:

[My layout isn't loading in my Magento admin view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862940/my-layout-isnt-loading-in-my-magento-admin-view/11864693#11864693)

= UPDATE =

You also need not to call `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule');` in your controller as is has been called in your `mymodule.xml`

OR

you can omit your `mymodule.xml` (no need to call it) by changing your controller's action into:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $myblock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule');
    $this->_addContent($myblock);
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

see the definition:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action

protected function _addContent(Mage_Core_Block_Abstract $block)
{
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    return $this;
}
```

those codes above do the same thing like the `mymodule.xml`, appending block `'mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule'` to the `content`

It's all your choice!

Comment: That's what it was! Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make sure your index action is being called properly?

when you do this :

```
<?php
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Adminhtml_MymoduleController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
{
public function indexAction() {
    echo "im here";exit; //<----does this display?
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule');
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

}

and then finally its important to load your layout first. so in my opnion change your index action to this :

```
<?php
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Adminhtml_MymoduleController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
{
public function indexAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();    // <---- This first
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule');// <---- then this
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

}

Comment: indexAction() is working correctly (echos ok) but no joy when changing the load order. Thanks.

Comment: can you confrim if your grid constructor is being called or not?

Comment: Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Mymodule_Grid::__construct() is called (twice actually!?) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't strictly related to the answer, but hopefully this might help someone.

Just in case anyone is reading this, completely bereft of hope - make sure there's a layout file in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout`.

I had no problems with my custom grid locally, but when I migrated it, it was displaying the symptoms above (blank screen etc)

It was due to me not copying that file over.